# How can I make a video file available for download?

Tags: html, href

I am trying to offer a download option of videos on my site.
I have direct links (which have .mp4/.webm ending) available for download (they are not hosted on my server if that matters).
This is what I tried:

```
     <a href="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.webm" download>Download</a>
```

It only works on chrome, in FireFox it will just open the video on the browser itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need a wrapper script which sets the Content-Type Content-Disposition headers appropriately, and outputs the file you want to serve.

In PHP this would be done like this:

**Filename: 624x260.php**

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a webm video
header('Content-type: video/webm');

// It will be called downloaded.webm
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.webm"');

readfile('624x260.webm');
?>
```

You would then link to the PHP file instead, as follows:

```
<a href="624x260.php">Download</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but now I have another question if you don't mind; I tried adding a video link which contains a username and password, like this: http://user:pass@stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.webm but it doesn't work for me. when I try to run it on a browser with the user and pass it works.

Comment: Try using an absolute link for the video in your PHP file (include the http://): ...    `readfile('http://user:pass@stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.webm');`

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. the file which I tried it on was actually .mp4, therefore I changed the content-type to "video/mp4" but it didn't help.

Comment: Is the file hosted on your server, or are you fetching it from a remote site? You could try using fopen() instead of readfile(), but you may have other cross-domain file policy issues. This might help too: http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php [also note that you will have to echo the output if you use fopen().. like this: `echo (fopen("http://user:pass@blah.com/vid.mp4", "r"));`]

Answer (score 1):

if you happen to have an apache server where you can edit the .htaccess file, add this line.

```
AddType application/octet-stream .webm
```

If you wish to not do this, you could do this through php as well.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```

HTML Code:

```
<a href="direct_download.php?file=fineline.mp3">Download the mp3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 adds the download attribute, which you have there in your example, but is empty. Add a value to the download attribute and hey presto.

ie change download to download="624x260.webm" in your a tag.

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download

For non-HTML5 compliant browsers, the most straightforward way would be to accompany the links with a direction to 'right click to download'.  This would cover the majority of cases and browsers.

An overview of a couple of techniques here, I realise you can't zip the files.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/ht/download_link.htm

There are multitude more involved ways to do this, including modifying the web server config, but not everyone has the access / know-how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The download attribute is supported in Chrome 14+ and Firefox 20+.

As an alternative for other browsers, you can use jQuery plugin from here 
http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/4

OR

http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/

You can make it downloadable like

```
<a href="http://video.webmfiles.org/elephants-dream.webm" class="download" target="_blank">Download</a>

        $(document).on("click", "a.download", function () {
            $.fileDownload($(this).prop('href'))
                .done(function () { alert('File download a success!'); })
                .fail(function () { alert('File download failed!'); });

            return false;
        });
```

Comment: I have firefox 21 and it doesn't work. in chrome it works though.